# Running Railo and Adobe Coldfusion Server on the same server

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfml

I have several Coldfusion sites on a Win 2K3 IIS6 server and I wanted to ease into Railo. I was hoping to install Railo on the same server and just set up a particular IIS virtual host to use Railo instead of Adobe CF server.

It seems Adobe CF Server will still process the request for .cfm files even though I pointed the isapi mapping to the Railo dll.

I shut down Adobe Coldfusion 8 service and got Railo working on the IIS virtual host but it takes about 15 or so seconds to process a single .cfm file with the now() function in it. If I run the same cfm file via the port Railo is running on it is very fast.

is it possible to run Railo and CF Server side by side without JRun? And why would Railo and IIS be so slow?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A number of people have done such. Some (like Mike Henke and Matt Woodward) have gone even further and installed Open BlueDragon, Railo and Adobe CF at the same time. Matt has a really nice blog posting on how to do it [here](http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2009/02/open-bluedragon-railo-coldfusion-on.html). He also has a nice set of presentation slides on this [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090418085608/http://www.mattwoodward.com/blog/index.cfm?event=showEntry&entryId=FFB409B3-4592-4E21-A1A8B58CC9551F92).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to download Railo Express (includes Jetty) and run that on a different port, like 8080.